# How can i store both a string and an int in one slot in a arraylist in c#

Tags: c#

I am making a listing program and I want to be able to make it so if you add more than one of the same products to the list it changes the string to say productx1, productx2 and so on. Any ideas?

Comment: How? don't!   Create a class, and have the list contain instances of that class

Comment: Create a proper object model of a line item with a product and an amount.

Comment: Please see [Microsoft's remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0#remarks) on using `ArrayList`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can create a class, struct or tuple and put them in a List.